# JavaFX detect when scrollbar movement is complete

Tags: javafx

Swing provided `java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent.getValueIsAdjusting()` which could be used to detect when a JScrollBar movement was completed. This was used in a legacy application so that it only requested data once rather than on every little scroll movement.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JScrollBar comp = new JScrollBar();
comp.addAdjustmentListener(e -> {
    if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        System.out.println("Finished " + e.getValue());
    }
});
frame.add(comp);
comp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 300));
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I'm looking for an equivalent method in JavaFX with ScrollBar. It appears that ScrollBar only has a way of monitoring the current value. I've reviewed the code in `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ScrollBarBehavior` but can see no obvious way to do this.

My workaround for now is fairly ugly. It uses a pair of event listeners to drag if the mouse is pressed, this state is used to maintain another valueProperty() which is only updated when the mouse is released.

Is there a better/easier way to do this?

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ScrollBar scrollbar = new ScrollBar();
    new ScrollBarFinishedAdjusting(scrollbar).valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println("Finished " + newValue);
    });
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(scrollbar));
    primaryStage.show();
}

private class ScrollBarFinishedAdjusting {
    private boolean mouseDown;
    private DoubleProperty value = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private ScrollBar scrollbar;

    public ScrollBarFinishedAdjusting(ScrollBar scrollbar) {
        this.scrollbar = scrollbar;
        scrollbar.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!mouseDown) {
                update();
            }
        });
        scrollbar.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, event -> {
            mouseDown = true;
        });
        scrollbar.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, event -> {
            mouseDown = false;
            update();
        });
        update();
    }

    private void update() {
        value.set(scrollbar.getValue());
    }

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty valueProperty() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Slider has this kind of functionality.

Comment: And is it that you dont need this behaviour when the user scrolls using scroll wheel instead of mouse button?

Comment: as mentioned by @jewelsea, Slider has this functionality because the value cannot be changed with the scroll wheel. Whereas in scrollbar the value can be changed with scrollwheel. So to make it consistent you need to suppress the scroll event.

Comment: why? whar exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I don’t see anything cleaner than what you’ve posted. As others have hinted, first ask if you really need this. E.g. If it’s ok to update on every frame rendering, that should be achievable without this (something akin to how virtualized controls are implemented).  Or you could use a slider: it might even be possible to make a slider look like a scroll bar just with CSS.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's input. Sorry I didn't make it clear in the question, but the scrollbar updates are used to request data from a backend database - an expensive operation, not something I want to do for every pixel movement of the scrollbar thumb, only on release.

Comment: You may wish to try a slider and see if it provides the functionality you want.  If it does, but the style isn’t his you want, then you could style the slider using CSS.  Or you could just stick with your scroll bar solution posted in your question if that works for you.